# Microsoft Office 2013 "Product Activation Failed", however I can still use office?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013, software-activation

I downloaded the legitamate 30 day trial version from Microsoft's website about 3 months ago, and my trial has expired about 2 months ago. My trial came to an end on 7/22/2014, however, I am still able to use Microsoft Office at its fullest, but instead of showing "Document title.docx - Word" in the application name, it shows "Document title.docx - Word (Product Activation Failed)".

Question 1: Is it the actual full version of office? (by which I mean ALL the features are enabled)

Question 2: Is this legal?

Question 3: If both of the above are true, why does Microsoft allow this?

Comment: [relevant](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-office_install/office-2013-working-fine-after-it-has-expired-bug/e4e71411-e7cf-4efe-9fa9-727f4aef587e)

Comment: I'm not a lawyer and you would of course have to read the EULA, but I'm gonna go out on a limb here and say that the answer to #2 is No.

Comment: 1 - no; 2 - unknown; 3 - N/A

Comment: If number 1 is no, which features am I missing out on?

Comment: The features that are deactivated are fully documented on Microsofts website

Comment: Where? Link please?

Comment: 1) Where have you downloaded Office and which version? (2) What kind of product key have you entered? (3) Did you rearm the installation (ignore if you don't know what this means)? (4) Does the activation wizard come up from time to time? (5) Post the output of this command: `cscript "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus`.

Comment: @harrymc, all that is in the description of the question. Please read more carefully. Downloaded from Office 365 website, and in the title, I put in that it is Office 2013. I am going to run that command when I get home, thanks.

Comment: I don't see this info in the question.

Comment: C:\Users\Kirill>cscript "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.V
BS" /dstatus
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Input Error: Can not find script file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\O
ffice15\OSPP.VBS".



And no, OSPP.VBS isn't in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15", however the Office15 directory does exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.blogsolute.com/microsoft-office-2013-trial-ends/26444/) someone in the same situation as you.

> But, in reality, I was able to edit documents and even save them. No Problem at all in other products too like PowerPoint or Excel.

**Question 1**

Yes, full functions, but it will end (see Q3).

**Question 2**

Pretty sure it isn't...

**Question 3**

If you go to the link above, you'll see that for the guy:

> On the last day, MS Word 2013 greeted me saying: The Trial of
>   Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 is expired. Editing in Word
>   has been disabled.

His "Microsoft Office has finally stopped working. Not that it doesn’t open but editing document functionality has been disabled. You can still open any file in read mode only."

So basically the program became useless. Maybe that answers your third question - Microsoft allows this because the program will become read-only eventually, even though not in 30 days.

I'd advise you to **purchase a license as soon as possible**, as you're close to the 3 month period too. Otherwise your work might be affected when the day comes. Better safe than sorry.